# Regular expression, replace "22,09" with "22.09"

Tags: mysql, database, regex

I am importing a dataset in csv format to a database.

The structure of the csv files are like this

> Part number, Description, Netto price, Brutto price, comment
>   11009, Ball Bearing, "22,09", "38,05", "Note, this article is the same as koyo xxxxxx"

As I am not yet familiar with regular expressions, can someone please put help me?

Or maybe a write perl script for me.

Thank you

Comment: What kind of answer do you want?  Different languages have different function names and slightly different syntax for regular expressions.  If you want perl code, you should say so explicitly.

Comment: Well, acutally, I just want to convert a few thousand lines, stored in a few files. I think perl would be ideal for this purpose. If you have some other method to suggest for me, you are welcome

Comment: Almost same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208923/how-do-i-change-datatype-of-an-imported-spreadsheet-in-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for that; it can be done in MySQL alone.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv'
INTO TABLE prices
FIELDS
  TERMINATED BY ','
  ENCLOSED BY '"'
(partno, desc, @net, @gross, comment)
SET
  net=REPLACE(@net, ',', '.'),
  gross=REPLACE(@gross, ',', '.'),
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can handle using Vim ([here's a quickstart](http://fosswire.com/post/2007/11/ultra-quick-start-in-vim/)) to edit your CSV files, this command in Vim would give you the behavior you want, assuming inputs are formed as such (`"xx,yy"` to `"xx.yy"`):

```
:%s/"\(\d\+\),\(\d\+\)"/"\1.\2"/g
```

You can then hit `:wq` to save your file and exit the program. That regex (`/"(\d+),(\d+)"/`) should also serve as a starting point in other programs (or languages) that accept regular expressions.

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed. I just recently started using vim, and I love the power of the editor!

Comment: hehe, I totally forgot to escape the +, ended up doing it the long way: `echo '11009, Ball Bearing, "22,09", "38,05", "Note, this article is the same as koyo xxxxxx"' | sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]*\),\([0-9][0-9]*\)/\1.\2/g'`

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to replace commas only when float numbers are in a string delimited by double quotes. This is the regexp you want :

```
/(?<=")(\d+),(\d+)(?=")/
```

Which would only match {22 ; 09} and {38 ; 05}.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you would do it in the Ruby programming language.  Not sure if this helps:

```
row = 'abc, "22,09", t'
row.gsub(/([0-9]+),([0-9]+)/, '\1.\2')
puts row       # result is: abc, "22.09", t
```

The call to gsub searches for any series of digits followed by a comma followed by any series of digits, and replaces the comma with a period.